# Is there before_filter in django as in rails?

Tags: django, django-views

Is there any feature available in django so that we can combine some filtering on all actions in the view of django, like before_filter: is available in rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. before_, around_ and after_ filter concepts aren't present in Django, but it isn't hard to write your own functions to do the same thing. There are also [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/signals/) and [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/class-based-views/#dynamic-filtering) that might accomplish what you're needing to do.

Comment: Can you please take a look at below answer and let us know what's the difference between Rails filters and Djano decorators.

Comment: Decorators can be used to execute code and then call the original function that was to be called, and even hand parameters to the original function. They basically accomplish the same thing as Rails' filters. This is what I was referring to when I said "...write your own functions to do the same thing...". I should have been more specific in that they could be applied as decorators.

Comment: Class-based views would be the easiest way to accomplish the same functionality for all functions within a specific controller or any controller action that needs the same functionality, as you can leverage inheritance to apply the decorators you need.

Answer (score 3):

I'm still learning Rails but from what I've observed so far python [decorators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Decorators) also seem to be used in Django in a very similar way to the before_filter in Rails.

Here's one example of it's usage in authenticating users: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator

Comment: I am not experienced Django user but Bradon can have a look on this and tell us the similarities between filters of rails and decorators of python.

Comment: The link mentioned no longer works. Can someone update it please?

Answer (score 1):

`decorators` can be used for this. your decorator can be the before_filter or after_filter depending on how whether it calls the decorated function first or last.

here is an example

```
@question_required
def show(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse(f'you are looking at {question_id}')
```

Here we have decorated the show function with `question_required` and want it to act as a before_filter. so we will define the decorator like this:

```
def question_required(func):
    def containing_func(*args, **kwargs):
        request = args[0]
        question_id = kwargs['question_id']
        try:
            question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return containing_func
```

As you can see above the decorator is first checking for the question to exist in the db. If it exists it calls the actual `show` function or it raises an exception.

In this way it acts like a before filter does in rails.