# DRYing up Django views request.user object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am building a web application and I finding there is a lot of replication in checking that the request.user matches the user who created the movie. Movie has a FK to the user so only users who created the specific movie can perform the appropriate actions on them.

```
@login_required
def edit_movie(request, slug, template_name="movies/edit_movie.html"):
    movie = get_object_or_404(Movie, slug=slug)
    if movie.user != request.user:
        raise HttpResponseForbidden
    # Rest of code omitted for brevity.

@login_required
def edit_screener(request, slug, template_name="movies/edit_screener.html"):
    movie = get_object_or_404(Movie, slug=slug)
    movie_media = movie.moviemedia_set.get(movie_type='screener')
    if movie.user != request.user:
        raise HttpResponseForbidden()
    # Rest of code omitted for brevity.


@login_required
def dashboard(request, template_name='movies/dashboard.html'):
    movies = Movie.objects.active().filter(
        user=request.user).order_by('-created_at')
    # Rest of code omitted for brevity.
```

I have a strong background in Ruby on Rails and we simply would use a before_filter :find_user   on the controller so it avoided the duplication. What is the best way in Django to handle this sort duplication?

J

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584512/is-there-before-filter-in-django-as-in-rails) might be relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is ok to show a 404 instead of 403 you could do this:

```
movie = get_object_or_404(Movie, slug=slug, user=request.user)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not create simple function that does that instead of copying same code?

```
def get_movie(slug, user):
    movie = get_object_or_404(Movie, slug=slug)
    if movie.user != user:
        raise Http403
    return movie
```

Comment: That is what I was thinking about doing as well.